# Javascript - dataset too large, need to only include data up to 1000 values that's spaced out evenly

Tags: javascript, math, conditional-statements

Basically I can only plot 1000 values on a chart but my dataset frequently has more than 1000 values.

So... let's say I have 3000 values - that's easy, every 3rd point is plotted (if i / 3 == 1). What about when it's a number like 2106? I'm trying to plot evenly.

```
for(var i = 0; i < chartdata.node.length; i++){
  //something in here
}
```

Comment: Is your `chartdata.node` array/list sorted?

Comment: yeah by date, chartdata is the array. chartdata.node.value is the number

Comment: @ShazboticusSShazbot take a look at my answer, too! I don't want to feel left out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your may have more or less than 1000 I would go with something like this

```
var inc = Math.floor(chartdata.node.length / 1000);

if ( inc==0 )
   inc=1;

for ( var i=0; i<chartdata.node.length; i+=inc )
 { 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Exactly 1000 points, slightly irregular spacing

Let *A* be the number of data points you have (i.e. 2106) and *B* be the number of data points you want to use (i.e. 1000). In a continuous case, you'd space your plot points at every *A/B* data points. With discrete data points, you can do the following: maintain a counter *C*, initialized to zero. **For every one of the *A* input data points, you add *B* to that counter. If the resulting value is larger than *A*, you plot the data point and subtract *A* from the counter.** On the whole, you'll have added the value *B A* times, and subtracted *A B* times, so you should end up with a zero counter again, having plotted exactly *B* data items.

You can tweak this to obtain different behaviour at the end points, e.g. to always include the first and last data point. Simply plot the first point unconditionally, then do the above scheme for the remaining points, i.e. with A=2105 and B=999. One benefit of this whole approach is that all of this works in integer arithmetic, so rounding errors will be of no concern to you.

## Perfectly regular spacing, but less data points

If even spacing is more important, then you can simply compute the amount by which you want to increment your index for every plot using floor(*A/B*). Due to the floor function, this will be a smaller number than the fractional resoult would be. In the worst case, a number which is *almost* two will get rounded down to one, resulting in only slightly more than 500 data points being actually plotted. These will be evenly spaced, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (in pseudo-code):

```
var desired_data_length = 1000;
for (var i = 0; i < desired_data_length; i++)
{
    var actual_i = int(float(i) / float(desired_data_length) * float(chartdata.length));
    // do something with actual_i as the index
}
```

This will use `desired_data_length` number of indices, and will linearly interpolate from `[0,desired_data_length)` to `[0,chartdata.length)`, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is purely numerical you may try [Typed Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays).